# How can I Calculate the z-score for each group in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, group-by

I am looking to compute the z-score of the independent variable "price" based on each proiperty group using python.

In other word, I need to calaulet the z-transform of the "apartments" group in "Type", the z-score of the "houses" group in "Type" and z-score for "NoInfo" group in "Type with changing the prices in independent variable "price" of all property groups with the z-score values of all groups. Note I am not looking to put the z-score values of all groups in a seperate columns. I am looking to put all z-score values of all groups in the same column "price".

For example, if I have a dataframe like below, how can I calculate the z-transform for each property group: apartment, NoInfo and NoInfo?

df =

```
     Name         Type               price 

0    gg         apartment            8 

1    hh         apartment            4

2    tty        apartment            0

3    ttyt       NoInfo               6

4    re         house                6 

5    ew         house                2

6    rr         house                0

7    tr         NoInfo               5

8    mm         NoInfo               0
```

I write the code below, but I have received an error "Length mismatch: Expected axis has 4906 elements, new values have 4910 elements "Do you have any idea how can I fix this error:

```
name = ['price']

price_zscore = lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std()

df[name] = df.groupby([df.Type])[name].transform(price_zscore)
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Your code works on your example (with *very* minor edits, for instance capitalizing `Price` in `name = ['price']`)

Comment: I did that and still have the same error "Do you have any idea how can I fix this error?"